# No translation for error message: "An error when loading mod menu - please try again"

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, localization, error-message

Trying to destroy user before signing moderator agreement gives me an error:

> An error when loading mod menu - please try again

> [image]

That error message currently isn't translatable ([not found in traducir](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=error%20when%20loading)).

Comment: Getting the error should be status-bydesign. The error not being translated should be fixed in traducir.

Comment: @Mast: I think the point of this post is that the string [doesn't seem to appear in Traducir](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=when%20loading%20mod), so the devs need to make it translatable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting! We rolled out the translatable string for this Aug 2, 2023.

> An error occurred when loading mod menu - please try again

Comment: For some reason there's [no result for that string](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=error%20when%20loading%20mod%20menu). Do you know why?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ it was changed to "An error occurred when loading mod menu - please try again", i.e. your search didn't contain the newly added "occurred" word.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard thanks. [String found](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19881).

Comment: It seems that I need to resign mod agreement to test the issue :-D

Comment: @αλεχολυτ you can recreate the error by loading a user's profile, [simulating being offline using your browser's developer tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29326005/369247), then attempting a moderator action